# TS2345: 'trustAccountIdentities' does not exist in type 'KeyProps' error in cdkv2

Tags: typescript, deployment, aws-cdk, bamboo, amazon-kms

I upgraded my cdk project from v1 to v2. It's complaining about trustAccountIdentities existance in cdkv2.

error at the time of build:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '{ enableKeyRotation: true; enabled: true; removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY; trustAccountIdentities: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeyProps'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'trustAccountIdentities' does not exist in type 'KeyProps'.

It was given same way in cdkv1. My code is as below

```
    const account = new AccountCustomResource(this, StackConfiguration.name+ '-BucketKmsAccountCustomResource');
     /** Added code to create Custom kms key*/ 
     const MyKmsKey =  new kms.Key(this, (mykey).toLowerCase(), {
      enableKeyRotation: true,
      enabled: true,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      trustAccountIdentities: true
     });
     MyKmsKey.addAlias(mykey);
```

I tried commenting trustAccountIdentities line and build worked fine but then it's giving issue while deployment with below error.

> Stack Deployments Failed: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::<arn#>:assumed-role/cdk-<some#>-deploy-role-<some#>-/aws-cdk-bamboo is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<some#>:role/cloud-services/pipeline-elevated-access with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy

Answer (score 1):

The `trustAccountIdentities` property is deprecated.  If you need it treated as `true`, use the `@aws-cdk/aws-kms:defaultKeyPolicies` [feature flag](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/aws-cdk-lib/cx-api/FEATURE_FLAGS.md).

That info is from the KMSProps [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/a2c633f1e698249496f11338312ab42bd7b1e4f0/packages/aws-cdk-lib/aws-kms/lib/key.ts#L499) docstrings.  It also explains that:

> If the `@aws-cdk/aws-kms:defaultKeyPolicies` feature flag is set (the default for new projects), this flag will always be treated as 'true' and does not need to be explicitly set.

Comment: Thank you @fedonev for your response. If by default feature flag of trustAccountIdentities property is true for cdk v2, then I don't need to mention that explicitly. In that case the deployment error is also not related, then how deployment error can be fixed? Could you please suggest?

Comment: @KJ21 The feature flag is the default for _new projects_, say the docs.  You are upgrading a project from v1, so it (probably) isn't new.  Did you try setting the feature flag?

Comment: Could you please suggest how to resolve the deployment error mentioned in original question?

AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::<arn#>:assumed-role/cdk-<some#>-deploy-role-<some#>-/aws-cdk-bamboo is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<some#>:role/cloud-services/pipeline-elevated-access with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy